# cloud build trigger from webhook not found

Tags: google-cloud-build

I have tried two approaches -- first I tried using CURL to post to the webhook location and I get "triggerError spanner trigger (project-id-number, trigger-name) not found", and then I thought perhaps this meant I should re-create the trigger from the command line. When I did so, it demands a repo-type argument, but nowhere in the documentation or help do I find what argument to provide for a google cloud source repositories repo, and all the options I've tried end up crashing the gcloud client with:
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): No such value for CloudSourceRepositories in Enum RepoTypeValueValuesEnum

Comment: Do you follow any documentation and can you provide any reproducible code?

Comment: I created this trigger through interaction with the web GUI, not through the gcloud CLI or anything similar, just by filling in the blanks in the GUI.

As for the second issue. I can show you how to reproduce it:
Create a Google cloud source repo. In my case, the branch is "main", not master. Try to create a webhook:
gcloud alpha builds triggers create webhook   --name=new-build   --repo=https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-name/r/repo-name  --repo-type="Cloud Source Repositories" --branch=main  --secret=projects/project-name/secrets/webhook-secret   --inline-config=build.yaml

Comment: The issue is I have no idea what the "repo-type" argument is supposed to be, and I don't see it anywhere in the documentation. I've tried several variations on "Cloud Source Repositories", "CloudSourceRepositories", singular versions, etc.  build.yaml is a file that contains my build configuration. This fails before that ever comes up with an issue with the repo type not matching a valid Enum value. I would like to know what the valid values are. I don't see it in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: I finally figured out what value the repo-type needs. In case anyone else is looking for this, I found it by grepping the google-cloud-sdk source for  RepoTypeValueValuesEnum.  It turns out it is "CLOUD_SOURCE_REPOSITORIES". So that at least enables me to create a build that is visible from my gcloud CLI

Comment: Now I can create the webhook trigger through use of the CLI, e.g. like this, but it doesn't show up on my project trigger page, and I therefore can't find the URL for it.
So if I create it using the GUI, I can't see it in the CLI and I get the missing spanner trigger error when I try to POST to the URL.  If I create it in the CLI, I can't see it in the GUI, and I don't know what the webhook URL is.
Here is the command I used to create it, (with project name and id number changed for privacy):

Comment: gcloud alpha builds triggers create webhook   --name=new-build   --repo=https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-name/r/repo-name  --repo-type=CLOUD_SOURCE_REPOSITORIES --branch=main  --secret=projects/project-id-num/secrets/webhook-secret/versions/1   --inline-config=build.yaml

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer so other people in the community will see it. Then I suggest you post another question regarding webhook trigger not showing in the trigger page for you to better track your raised concerns.

Comment: I did not solve the whole problem -- I figured out only that --repo-type needs to be "CLOUD_SOURCE_REPOSITORIES".  I gave up on having a webhook trigger, because I couldn't make it work.

I changed to using a pub/sub trigger instead, and created a cloud function that writes to the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the region of the webhook when configuring it on the UI into global. That worked for me!